# Looping Until A Condition Takes Place

Tags: c++, loops, dice

How do I continue to keep the player rolling the dice till they roll the correct number or lose?

I need the game or dice to continue going through the loop. What to modify to make this happen?

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int dice_num1, dice_num2 = 0; 
int roll_dice;
int dice_num3, dice_num4 = 0;
int roll_dice2;
char repeat = 'y'; 

while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y') 
{   
    srand(time(0));                                                
    dice_num1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dice_num2 = rand() % 6 + 1; 
    roll_dice = dice_num1 + dice_num2;

    cout <<"Player rolled: "<< dice_num1<<" + "<<dice_num2<<" = "<<roll_dice<<endl;
    cout <<"\nThe point is "<<roll_dice<<endl;

    dice_num3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dice_num4 = rand() % 6 + 1; 
    roll_dice2 = dice_num3 + dice_num4;

    cout <<"\nPlayer rolled: "<< dice_num3<<" + "<<dice_num4<<" = "<<roll_dice2<<endl;



    if (roll_dice2 == 7 || roll_dice2 == 11)
    {
        cout << "Congrats you are a Winner!" << endl ;
    } 

    else if (roll_dice2 == 2 || roll_dice2 == 3 || roll_dice2 == 12)
    {
        cout  << "Sorry, you rolled craps, You lose!" << endl; 
    }

    else if (roll_dice2 == 4 || roll_dice2 == 5 ||roll_dice2 == 6 ||roll_dice2 == 8 || roll_dice2 == 9 || roll_dice2 == 10)
      {     
        dice_num3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        dice_num4 = rand() % 6 + 1; 
    int sum_num2 = dice_num3 + dice_num4;

     if( sum_num2 == roll_dice2 )
            {
                cout << "Congrats you are a Winner!" << endl;
                break;
            } 
    else if( sum_num2 == 7 )
            {
                cout << "Sorry, You Lose!" << endl;
                break;
            }
  }
cout <<"\nAnother game? Y(es) or N(o)"  << endl;
    cin >> repeat;

if (repeat == 'n' || repeat == 'N') 
{
cout <<"Thank you for playing!"<< endl;
return 0;
}
}
}
```

This is my output:

```
Player rolled: 4 + 5 = 9

The point is 9

Player rolled: 5 + 3 = 9

Another game? Y(es) or N(o)
```

This is what my output needs to be:

```
Player rolled: 2 + 2 = 4

The point is 4

Player rolled: 4 + 5 = 9
Player rolled: 5 + 1 = 6
Player rolled: 1 + 2 = 3
Player rolled: 2 + 3 = 5
Player rolled: 1 + 2 = 3
Player rolled: 3 + 5 = 8
Player rolled: 2 + 4 = 6
Player rolled: 6 + 3 = 9
Player rolled: 6 + 2 = 8
Player rolled: 3 + 4 = 7

You rolled 7 and lost!
```

How do I get this to continue rolling the dice in the loop?

Comment: I've never been into gambling, much. Well, at least I now know the rules of craps.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to keep the code similar to your original structure. This should do what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    srand(clock());

    int die1, die2, total, point;

    die1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    die2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    total = die1 + die2;

    cout << "Player rolled: " << die1 << " + " << die2 << " = " << total << endl;

    if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12) {
        cout << "You rolled " << total << " and lost!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (total == 7 || total == 11) {
        cout << "You rolled " << total << " and won!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "The point is " << total << endl;

    point = total;

    while (true) {
        die1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        die2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        total = die1 + die2;
        cout << "Player rolled: " << die1 << " + " << die2 << " = " << total << endl;

        if (total == point) {
            cout << "You rolled " << total << " and won!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (total == 7) {
            cout << "You rolled " << total << " and lost!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is this complete? I couldn't get it to run, i tried putting return on it.

Comment: I tested it before I posted. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: That was in your original code... but I'll update my post with a different method.

Comment: `srand` and `system` are both defined in `cstdlib`. You need to add `#include <cstdlib>` at the beginning (as in the OP's sample code) and then this error goes away. However, I still get errors of `sh: pause: command not found`.

Comment: Wow, I am not getting those problems at all. Updated the code once again to remove system commands and just purely use return.

Comment: Yeah, it's somewhat compiler dependent. For instance, if I compile it with `g++` I get the error, but if I compile with `clang++` then I dont get the error.

Comment: Ah, I'm using VisualStudio.